# How to just use namespace and class name in tag for YamlDotNet

Tags: yamldotnet

I'm trying to serialize an object with nested Dictionary properties from C# (YamlDotNet) to Java using SnakeYaml to deserialize on server side.  Oddly this was working fine with property in the form:

```
public IDictionary<InstrumentId, BidAsk> InstrumentBidAsk { get; private set; }
```

but for another object when there is an extra layer of nesting:

```
public IDictionary<ClearingHouse, IDictionary<InstrumentId, BidAsk>> InstrumentBidAsk { get; private set; }
```

Class InstrumentId is no longer serialized into an object.  Intead a LinkedHashMap is created.

To fix this issue, I thought perhaps the following option on YamlDotNet could be used on serializer:

```
Serializer(SerializationOptions.Roundtrip, namingConvention);
```

This then includes information on the type, which I was hoping to use on the Java side in tag mappings to create the appropriate object rather than getting a LinkedHashMap.

The tag that gets created include not just namespace and class name, but also all the information on the assembley, such as version cutlture, public key token etc.

For example, from Java to C# the following tag might be created:

```
!!project.package.bidask.InstrumentId
```

But from C# to Java the following is created:

```
!Project.Package.Configuration.InstrumentId,%Project.DataModel,%20Version=1.0.0.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=null
```

Is there a way to show concise tag mappings?

From Java to C# the top level Yaml gives key and value but makes no mention of HashMap:

```
CME: ? !!project.package.bidask.InstrumentId [fieldNames] : !!project.package.bidask.BidAsk [fieldNames]
```

From C# to Java full information on the Dictionary and the generic types is given:

```
CME: !System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602[[Project.DataModel.Configuration.InstrumentId,%20Project.DataModel,%20Version=1.0.0.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=null],[Project.DataModel.Configuration.BidAskSize,%20Project.DataModel,%20Version=1.0.0.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=null]],%20mscorlib,%20Version=4.0.0.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 &o0 !Project.DataModel.Configuration.InstrumentId,%20Project.DataModel,%20Version=1.0.0.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=null [fieldNames]: !Project.DataModel.Configuration.BidAskSize,%20Project.DataModel,%20Version=1.0.0.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=null [fieldNames]
```

Can someone suggest how to serialize in more concise fashion like SnakeYaml as this will make it easier to determine appropriate tag mapping on Java side?

Particularly, it would be useful not to have information on Dictionary as I don't think this is required - YAML syntax should cover key value relationship.

Comment: Without SerializationOptions.Roundtrip, the only difference I can see between the YAML sent from C# to Java and a very similar YAML but without the extra layer is the symbol &o0, &o1, &o2 etc.  If there is a way to switch this off, perhaps it will call the appropriate constructor for InstrumentId rather than remaining a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there is a good way to fix this using tag mappings, but in the end I added a fix by going through the collection and creating the appopriate objects from the LinkedHashMap in my code.